# Extra Data from Oracle SQL Subquery(and sub, sub query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query/subquery.  I am trying to get the CIty, State, and Zipcode from the record in the AOD table and the First and Last from the Employee Original Date table.  Can anyone provide guidance on how to extract the data form the sub query?  Thank you!

```
   SELECT eod.FIRST_NAME
    ,eod.LAST_NAME
    ,eod.SSN
    ,aodf.SSN
    ,aodf.CITY
    ,aodf.STATE
    ,aodf.ZipCode

FROM EMPLOYEE_ORIG_DATE eod

JOIN

    (SELECT aod.ORIG_DATE
        ,aod.SSN
        ,aod.ADDRESS_KEY
        ,aod.Address_1 as AddressLine1
        ,aod.Address_2 as AddressLine2
        ,aod.City
        ,aod.State
        ,aod.Zip as ZipCode
        ,aod.Country as CountryCode
        ,aod.Telephone as HomeNumber
    FROM ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE aod
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT SSN, MAX(ORIG_DATE) ORIG_DATE
            FROM ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE
            GROUP BY SSN) aod2
    ON aod.SSN = aod2.SSN 
    AND aod.ORIG_DATE = aod2.ORIG_DATE) aodf

ON eod.SSN = aodf.SSN
AND eod.ADRESS_KEY = aodf.ADDRESS_KEY
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ORIG_DATE.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 3149
```

Comment: you did it already in your select. or what do you mean by extract the data from subselect?

Comment: From a sub-query, you can only read the selected columns. If you have nested subqueries, you'll have to select these columns in each subquery.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for rewriting to simplify the query, then you may consider using `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function to include all the matching ties for returning records :

```
SELECT CITY, STATE, ZipCode, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
  FROM
  (
  SELECT eod.FIRST_NAME,
         eod.LAST_NAME,
         eod.SSN,
         aod.SSN,
         aod.CITY,
         aod.STATE,
         aod.ZipCode,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY SSN ORDER BY ORIG_DATE DESC ) ORIG_DATE
    FROM EMPLOYEE_ORIG_DATE eod
    JOIN ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE aod
      ON eod.SSN = aod.SSN
     AND eod.ADRESS_KEY = aod.ADDRESS_KEY
   WHERE P_COMPANY_ID_I = 3149
   )   
 WHERE ORIG_DATE = 1
```

where `PARTITION BY` replaces `GROUP BY`, and `ORIG_DATE DESC` replaces `MAX(ORIG_DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the most recent row from `ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE` for each `SSN` in `EMPLOYEE_ORIG_DATE`, then I would expect window functions.

I am guessing you just want one row, even if there are duplicates on the most recent date, so I recommend `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT eod.*, aod.*
FROM EMPLOYEE_ORIG_DATE eod JOIN
     (SELECT aod.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aod.SSN ORDER BY ORIG_DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE aod
     ) aod
     ON aod.SSN = eod.SSN
WHERE aod.seqnum = 1 AND
      eod.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 3149
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I got multiple entries for SSN's that had different ORIG_DATES

Comment: @Chuck0185 . . . If you have multiple SSNs, then that is because there are duplicated in `eod`.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, the eod table has an ORIG_DATE field as well so I am going to need to pull most recent ORIG_DATE from both tables.  So I pulled the sub query from your example.  I am trying to pull the most recent ORIG_DATE for each SSN in the ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE table.  However when I run the below SQL I receive the following error message: "ORA-00904: "SEQNUM": invalid identifier"


SELECT aod.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aod.SSN ORDER BY aod.ORIG_DATE DESC) as seqnum
FROM ADDRESS_ORIG_DATE aod
WHERE P_COMPANY_ID_I = 1234
AND seqnum = 1